# Using faster pandas groupby class on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, group-by, sklearn-pandas

Short version:
I need help applying someone else's groupby class on multiple pandas columns and with more complicated functions.

Long version:
Someone else (Elizabeth Santorella) wrote a python class to significantly speed up groupby and groupby-apply operations and wrote instructions for it (links below). Note: the code featured in the blog post is not the same as the code on the github page.

https://github.com/esantorella/hdfe/blob/master/hdfe/groupby.py

http://esantorella.com/2016/06/16/groupby/

The class works very well for applying simple user-defined functions on groups in one column (see my code using the class below). I have two issues:

1. I cannot figure out how to use this groupby class groupings on multiple columns.
2. I want to use this groupby class on more complicated functions that take more arguments than just one column value, but I cannot get a dummy version of such a function to work either.

This code seems great and has some documentation, I'm just not educated enough to use it. I have edited this question to include a simple squaring function (squareit) and a dummy sklearn regression function (dummypredict). The squareit function will work with the Groupby class with one categorical column but not with two. The dummypredict function is not working with the Groupby class at all. I appreciate any help, and this is what I have tried so far.

```
# import
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import time

# these are required for Groupby class
from typing import Union, Tuple, Callable, Any

# timing code setup
time.clock = time.time

# choose regressor
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# groubpy class definition written by E. Santorella
class Groupby:
    def __init__(self, keys: Union[np.ndarray, pd.Series]):
        """

        :param keys: List of group identifiers. Both __init__ and apply will run
            much faster if keys is already sorted.
        """
        self.keys = keys
        try:
            already_sorted = np.issubdtype(keys.dtype, np.number) and (
                np.all(np.diff(keys) >= 0)
            )
        except ValueError:
            already_sorted = False
        if already_sorted:
            keys = np.squeeze(keys)
            if keys.ndim > 1:
                raise ValueError("keys should be 1-dimensional")

            self.already_sorted = True
            new_idx = np.concatenate(([1], np.diff(keys) != 0))
            self.first_occurrences = np.where(new_idx)[0]
            self.keys_as_int: np.ndarray = np.cumsum(new_idx) - 1
            assert isinstance(self.keys_as_int, np.ndarray)
            self.n_keys = self.keys_as_int[-1] + 1

        else:
            self.already_sorted = False
            _, self.first_occurrences, self.keys_as_int = np.unique(
                keys, return_index=True, return_inverse=True
            )
            self.n_keys = max(self.keys_as_int) + 1
        self.indices = self._set_indices()

    def _set_indices(self):
        if self.already_sorted:
            indices = [
                slice(i, j)
                for i, j in zip(self.first_occurrences[:-1], self.first_occurrences[1:])
            ]
            indices.append(slice(self.first_occurrences[-1], len(self.keys_as_int)))
            indices = np.array(indices)
        else:
            indices = [[] for _ in range(self.n_keys)]
            for i, k in enumerate(self.keys_as_int):
                indices[k].append(i)
            indices = np.array([np.array(elt) for elt in indices])
        return indices

    def apply(
        self,
        function_: Callable[[np.ndarray], Any],
        array: Union[np.ndarray, pd.Series],
        broadcast: bool = True,
        shape: Tuple = None,
        order: str = "c",
        as_dataframe: bool = False,
    ):
        """
        Applies a function to each group, where groups are defined by self.keys_as_int
        (or, equivalently, as the argument of __init__.)
        If broadcast=True, first dimension of output will equal first dimension of
        "array", as in Pandas "transform".
        If broadcast=False, first dimension of output equals self.n_keys, as in Pandas
        "groupby".

        :param function_: function to be applied to each group
        :param array: np.ndarray or similar. Should have same first dimension as
        self.keys_as_int.
        :param broadcast: bool
        :param shape: Shape of output. Can be up to 3-dimensional.
            First dimension must be array.shape[0] (if broadcast=True)
            or self.n_keys (if broadcast=False). Default is for output to be
            one-dimensional.
        :param order: Should output be c-ordered or fortran-ordered?
        :param as_dataframe: if False, returns output as ndarray; if True, returns
        output
            as DataFrame with keys as indices
        :return:
        """
        if isinstance(array, pd.Series):
            names = [array.name]
            array = np.asarray(array)
        elif isinstance(array, pd.DataFrame):
            names = array.columns
            array = array.values
        else:
            names = [None]

        assert isinstance(array, np.ndarray)

        if broadcast:
            result = np.zeros(array.shape[0] if shape is None else shape, order=order)
            assert result.shape[0] == array.shape[0]

            # np.take doesn't allow slice arguments, so this has to be more verbose
            # than when not already sorted
            if self.already_sorted:
                if array.ndim == 1:
                    for idx in self.indices:
                        result[idx] = function_(array[idx])
                elif array.ndim == 2:
                    for idx in self.indices:
                        result[idx] = function_(array[idx, :])
                elif array.ndim == 3:
                    for idx in self.indices:
                        result[idx] = function_(array[idx, :, :])
                else:
                    raise NotImplementedError("Can't have more than 3 dims")
            else:
                for idx in self.indices:
                    result[idx] = function_(np.take(array, idx, 0))
            if as_dataframe:
                return pd.DataFrame(index=self.keys, data=result)
            return result

        result = np.zeros(self.n_keys if shape is None else shape, order=order)
        assert result.shape[0] == self.n_keys
        if self.already_sorted:
            if array.ndim == 1:
                for k, idx in enumerate(self.indices):
                    result[k] = function_(array[idx])
            elif array.ndim == 2:
                for k, idx in enumerate(self.indices):
                    result[k] = function_(array[idx, :])
            elif array.ndim == 3:
                for k, idx in enumerate(self.indices):
                    result[k] = function_(array[idx, :, :])
            else:
                raise NotImplementedError("Can't have more than 3 dims")

        else:
            for first_occurrence, idx in zip(self.first_occurrences, self.indices):
                result[self.keys_as_int[first_occurrence]] = function_(
                    np.take(array, idx, 0)
                )

        if as_dataframe:
            return pd.DataFrame(
                index=self.keys[self.first_occurrences], data=result, columns=names
            )
        return result

# a simple squaring function with one input
def squareit(x):
    y = x*x
    return y

# dummy regression function with three inputs
def dummypredict(data_in, yvar, xvars):
        
    # create df_train from data_in based on actuals not being null
    df_train = data_in[data_in['actual'].notnull()]
    
    # create df_predict from data_in based on actuals being null
    df_predict = data_in[data_in['actual'].isnull()]
    
    # fit the coefficients using the regressor
    regr.fit(df_train[xvars], df_train[yvar])
        
    # we create the prediction matrix
    X_predict = df_predict[xvars]
    
    # we assign predicted values to 
    df_predict['forecast'] = regr.predict(X_predict)
        
    # concatenate all data
    data_full = pd.concat([df_train, df_predict], axis = 0, ignore_index = True)
        
    #return coef
    return data_full

# original dataframe, not used for functions:
n_obs = 10**4
n_categories = 10**3
first_cat = np.random.choice(n_categories, n_obs)
np.random.seed(2016)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, n_obs)
df = pd.DataFrame({'first cat': first_cat,
                   'actual': y})

# decimal level of time reporting
n_decimals = 5

# dataframe setup code, uses two categories 
n_obs = 10**5
np.random.seed(20416)

# list of category labels per category
first_cat_ls = ['Albany', 'Augusta','Ashland','Angoon','Aniak','Anvik','Appleton',
             'Arcata', 'Arctic', 'Asheville', 'Abilene', 'Anaktueuk', 'Aspen',
             'Athens', 'Atka', 'Atlanta', 'Atlantic', 'Atqasuk','Anchorage',
             'Austin']
second_cat_ls = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bear', 'Hog', 'Parrot','Mongoose','Tiger', 'Lion',
             'Aardvark','Ant','Roach','Pigeon','Spider','Elk','Emu', 'Mouse',
             'Elephant','Human','Muskrat','Horse','Raccoon','Hummingbird',
             'Sloth', 'Termite',]

# make category arrays
first_category = np.random.choice(first_cat_ls, n_obs)
second_category = np.random.choice(second_cat_ls, n_obs)

# make array of actuals data
actual = abs(np.random.normal(1, 10, n_obs))

# creating two features randomly
feature_1 = abs(np.random.normal(2, 7, n_obs))
feature_2 = abs(np.random.normal(1, 7, n_obs))

# creating the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'first_cat': first_category,
                   'second_cat': second_category,
                    'feat1'   : feature_1,
                    'feat2'   : feature_2,
                   'actual': actual})

# creating two features again for variability
feature_1 = abs(np.random.normal(1, 3, n_obs))
feature_2 = abs(np.random.normal(1, 3, n_obs))

# creating another data frame to "predict" with
df2 = df.copy(deep=True)

# nulling out the actuals because df2 is the subset
# that will have a forecast made
df2['actual'] = np.nan

# create new df to feed into regression code made of df1 & 2
# groups are same in both and are fitted/predicted together
df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis = 0)

# sorting
df = df.sort_values(['first_cat','second_cat','actual'])

#%%

# simple squaring function with Groupby class works & creates warning (below):
start = time.clock()
x = Groupby(df['first_cat']).apply(squareit, df['actual'], broadcast=True)
# VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences 
# (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) 
# is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' 
#  when creating the ndarray. indices = np.array([np.array(elt) for elt in indices])
print('time to compute group squares with Groupby class: {0}'\
      .format(round(time.clock() - start, n_decimals)))
    
# lamda apply method - slightly slower
start = time.clock()
df.groupby(['first_cat']).apply(lambda x: squareit(df['actual']))
print('time to compute group squares with lambda method on groupby apply: {0}'\
      .format(round(time.clock() - start, n_decimals)))
    
# simple squaring function with native pandas - slightly slower
start = time.clock()
x = df.groupby(['first_cat'])['actual'].transform(squareit)
print('time to compute group squares with Pandas transform: {0}'\
      .format(round(time.clock() - start, n_decimals)))
    
# dummy regression function with standard pandas / sklearn works
start = time.clock()
x = df.groupby(['first_cat']).apply(dummypredict, 'actual', ['feat1','feat2'])
print('time to compute group regressions with standard Pandas / sklearn: {0}'\
      .format(round(time.clock() - start, n_decimals)))

# simple squaring function with Groupby class does not work with two categoricals:
x = Groupby(df[['first_cat','second_cat']]).apply(squareit, df['actual'], broadcast=True)
# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
    
# using the dummy regression function with Groupby class does not work
x = Groupby(df['first_cat']).apply(dummypredict, 'actual', ['feat1','feat2'], broadcast=True)
# apply() got multiple values for argument 'broadcast'

# this also did not work
x = Groupby(df['first_cat']).apply(dummypredict('actual', ['feat1','feat2']), broadcast=True)
# dummypredict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'xvars'
```

Comment: Can you show your real function? Does it work with current pandas? The blog post is 7 years old and the code is producing warnings which suggest it may not be worth pursuing. I'd imagine there are better options if you share your actual code/task/goal.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I'm also quite skeptical

Comment: @jqurious, I have added my own functions that I am trying to use in the code at the bottom of the post. The Groupby class code was pretty long, so I avoided adding it to the question. I have added the code now. Yes, it's old, but it's still quite fast for custom functions. It is slow for simple things like means and summations. I appreciate you taking a look.

Comment: Have you compared the speed to the latest version of pandas groupby?

Comment: @mozway I've edited the post to have all the requisite code in one spot. The custom class was very long so I excluded it for brevity.

Comment: @pyCthon thank you for your question - I'm using pd.__version__ = 1.4.4. I can test on 2.0.3 later today.

Comment: Yes, but I imagine pandas has improved things since 2016/17 so the comparisons could be pointless. We're not looking for the `Groupby` code, we're looking for the "complicated functions" you're using. (The example functions you've shown can be implemented without using `.apply` at all - so they don't help as much.)

Comment: @jqurious I see what you mean. As to the age of pandas, I'm using pd.__version__ = 1.4.4 which is fairly recent. Regarding the "complicated function," I'm using scikitlearn to create regressions fit/predict for individual groups within a dataframe. I wasn't able to figure out how to get sklearn to work on the whole dataframe and create individual fit/predict coefficients in one shot. I can create some dummy code later, thank you for asking.

Comment: @jqurious I created a new dataframe that is more representative of my data in the edited code and the performance increase I saw with the Groupby class disappeared entirely. It would appear that the code in Dr. Santorella's blog post, which has a very high number of groups as compared to the # of rows (1 group per 10 rows), allows for a unique circumstance in which the custom Groupby class code is still faster than native pandas methods. However I do not foresee myself being in such a situation. Regardless I have provided the edits I promised.

Comment: @pyCthon, I had tested Dr. Santorella's original dataframe and code in the latest pandas version and the custom Groupby class was still faster than native methods. However, as I stated in another comment, the dataframe created by Dr. Santorella was somewhat special and perhaps not representative of what most users may face. Please see my comment directed at jqurious. While not applicable to data I normally see, this Groupby class may be valuable to others.